# How do change a particular option in linux kernel config file?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, cross-compilation

I tried to follow the default config file for my Creator CI20 in particular setting the CONFIG_HID as follow:

```
# CONFIG_HID is not set
```

See ref [here](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/mips/configs/ci20_defconfig#n100).

However everytime, I do a:

```
$ make menuconfig
<Exit>+<Save>
```

It turns back to:

```
CONFIG_HID=y
```

How do I make sure to have `CONFIG_HID=n` in my case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You certainly have checked another option which automatically enables CONFIG_HID.

While in menuconfig, you can use '/' to search for CONFIG_HID and find which other option enables it.